# Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, crud

Can somebody recommend any framework to facilitate CRUD development in JSF 2.0?

Aspects I value most:

- As lightweight as possible; *limited* dependencies on third party libraries
- Support for an *evolving* domain model
- Limited need for repetitive coding; support for scaffolding and/or metaannotations

Any hints highly appreciated!
Yours,
J.

Comment: Just came across Krank, but it's not very much alive: http://code.google.com/p/krank/  Not JSF2-ready, but I like the ideas.  Does this inspire somebody?

Comment: Why not to use some tool which can generate a "crud application" for you? For example, Netbeans can do that http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

CRUD is indeed a piece of cake using JSF 2.0 provided standard facility: a [`@ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) bean in combination with a [`<h:dataTable>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/jsp/h/dataTable.html) basically already suffices. Here's a code example which is shamelessly copied from [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html).

Bean:

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<Item> list;
    private Item item = new Item();
    private boolean edit;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // list = dao.list();
        // Actually, you should retrieve the list from DAO. This is just for demo.
        list = new ArrayList<Item>();
        list.add(new Item(1L, "item1"));
        list.add(new Item(2L, "item2"));
        list.add(new Item(3L, "item3"));
    }

    public void add() {
        // dao.create(item);
        // Actually, the DAO should already have set the ID from DB. This is just for demo.
        item.setId(list.isEmpty() ? 1 : list.get(list.size() - 1).getId() + 1);
        list.add(item);
        item = new Item(); // Reset placeholder.
    }

    public void edit(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
        edit = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        // dao.update(item);
        item = new Item(); // Reset placeholder.
        edit = false;
    }

    public void delete(Item item) {
        // dao.delete(item);
        list.remove(item);
    }

    public List<Item> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isEdit() {
        return edit;
    }

    // Other getters/setters are actually unnecessary. Feel free to add them though.

}
```

Page:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Really simple CRUD</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>List items</h3>
        <h:form rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">
            <h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>#{item.id}</h:column>
                <h:column><f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>#{item.value}</h:column>
                <h:column><h:commandButton value="edit" action="#{bean.edit(item)}" /></h:column>
                <h:column><h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{bean.delete(item)}" /></h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty bean.list}">
            <p>Table is empty! Please add new items.</p>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!bean.edit}">
            <h3>Add item</h3>
            <h:form>
                <p>Value: <h:inputText value="#{bean.item.value}" /></p>
                <p><h:commandButton value="add" action="#{bean.add}" /></p>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.edit}">
            <h3>Edit item #{bean.item.id}</h3>
            <h:form>
                <p>Value: <h:inputText value="#{bean.item.value}" /></p>
                <p><h:commandButton value="save" action="#{bean.save}" /></p>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Further, Netbeans has [some useful wizards](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html) to genreate a CRUD application based on a datamodel.

Comment: ah, I looked for that article but couldn't find it. And was lazy to give a complete example myself :) (+1)

Comment: Yeah, the example code is appreciated.  Still I'm wondering if there isn't a way to generate all this code, driven by a set of annotated Entity objects.

Comment: The answer doesn't fully fit all requirements I had in mind.  Though, it looks like the best answer available, so I'll mark it as accepted.  (I'm new to StackOverflow... Is this the right thing to do?)

Comment: You can also consider using Netbeans' builtin wizards. I edited the answer to include a link.

Comment: @Matt: don't think do. Perhaps you just need to add the item to the list?

Comment: Ah, nevermind - looks like it's due to a [bug in PrimeFaces 2.2.1 DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422151/). Sorry to bug you!

Comment: @BalusC , What if I want to create a separate page for editing the item, with the bean being ViewScoped.
I currently do the following steps:
1. Put the item in the session
2. Redirect to the edit page.
3. On the edit page, I get the bean from session using ui:repeat or f:param.

Is it the right way?

Comment: Will this work if i aim to update multiple rows at the same time ?

Answer (score 7):

JSF 2.0 itself. CRUD is very easy to do with JSF alone - no need for any other framework. You need

- 1 managed bean (annotated with `@ManagedBean`)
- 2 xhtml pages (facelets) - one for list and one for edit/create
- A `<h:dataTable>` with an`edit` link/button, by which you set the current row object in the managed bean (using `action="#{bean.edit(currentRowObject)}"`). (In JSF 1.2 this was achieved by `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`)
- Action methods (`void`, with no arguments) to handle the operations
- `@PostConstruct` to load the data initially.

Comment: Hi Bozho,

Thank you for the reply.

I've added an additional 'requirement' to the original question: Limited need for manual coding.  

I understand your answer, but on a large domain model, the manual approach remains cumbersome.

I'm wondering if somthing Grails-like exists, but in pure JSF.

Thank you , J.

Comment: Isn't setPropertyActionListener unneeded in JSF 2.0, as we can pass objects as arguments?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen  indeed. thanks for reminding me. added to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I created this one to speed up process of jsf crud application creation: https://github.com/ignl/happyfacescrud
Out of box search, lazy data table, viewing/editing, custom components that reduces code dramatically and of course flexible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @Ignas Is happyfacescrud can do database reverse engineering for generating jsf pages and its respective beans?

Answer (score 2):

I found this article useful as well:

**Conversational CRUD in Java EE 6**

http://www.andygibson.net/blog/tutorial/pattern-for-conversational-crud-in-java-ee-6/

By *Andy Gibson*

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as described: Creating as-fast-as-possible CRUD-App in JEE6.

Beautiful Generator found at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbizmo/

After defining (Graph-Editor!) your Business-Model/Domain-Model, JBizMo creates the database and a whole CRUD-App out of the Box.

- i18n, JAAS, also supported
- Views and Menus are generated
- ... a bunch of parameters to define ...

Comment: @Jav_Rock,Michael Leitner  Where can I find the tutorial for JBizMo?

Comment: @Sampath the tutorial is also in the download (=Files) section of sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

I found an opensource crud generator for JSF+Primefaces

http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Primefaces

And also it generate crud for most of the frameworks http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/