# How to dynamically add JSF components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, dynamic-forms

Can I add JSF components dynamically? I need to have a form with a button which should add one `<h:inputText>` to the form. Is this possible?

I know this should be possible in JavaScript somehow. Do anybody know how to do this in JSF? I think the major problem is how do I get or set values of new inputs via `#{value}`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use an iterating component like `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>` to display a dynamically sized `List` of entities. Make the bean `@ViewScoped` to ensure that the list is remembered across postbacks on the same view instead of recreated over and over.

Kickoff example with `<h:dataTable>` (when using `<ui:repeat>` simply replace `<h:dataTable>` by `<ui:repeat>`, and `<h:column>` by e.g. `<li>` or `<div>`):

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:column><h:inputText value="#{item.value}" /></h:column>
        <h:column><h:commandButton value="remove" action="#{bean.remove(item)}" /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="add" action="#{bean.add}" />
    <h:commandButton value="save" action="#{bean.save}" />
</h:form>
```

Managed bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Item> items;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add() {
        items.add(new Item());
    }

    public void remove(Item item) {
        items.remove(item);
    }

    public void save() {
        System.out.println("items: " + items);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class Item {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Item[value=%s]", value);
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400)
- [How to create dynamic JSF form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614)
- [How to implement a dynamic list with a JSF 2.0 Composite Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358066)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885)

Comment: thanks, was thinking the same thing, only wondering if it was the best way to do it = D

Comment: True. The only alternative would be creating components programmatically like `new HtmlInputText()` and so on, but that would only result in nasty and opaque code in managed bean.

Comment: Hi, @BalusC, is it appropriate to add a field "name" to Item class? I need to save the items into DB and i must read them from DB too.

Comment: I did just this approach. But when I enter a new value on the added input and hit submit, the list on the backing bean is not updated. What can be wrong? My items are a List<String>, could be it? It can't change the string on the List?

Comment: @JSeven: [The `String` class is indeed immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780858/using-uirepeathinputtext-on-a-liststring-doesnt-update-model-values/). Every Java developer should know this.

Comment: I know that. I followed this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690317/how-to-add-hinputtext-dynamically-in-jsf and since I don't know precisely the inner workings of JSF, I thought it could maybe replace the String on the list with the new one instead of changing it.

Comment: @JSeven: Awkward. I posted a comment over there to protect the future innocent.

Comment: This is so much better than what Ive been doing thanks

Comment: Hi, @BalusC, if there are other inputs (beside the dynamic one) in the form with a set of validations or are marked as required then how to achieve the same thing? In my case, the action won't execute at all if there are validation errors.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you very much man! I am new in jsf and you saved my day! Actually i am using oracle adf and jdeveloper. Is there any way i can set the bean state through interface in jdeveloper.

Answer (score 1):

It's should be like that

Bind a form tag to the bean property

```
<form binding="#{myBean.myform}">...</form>
```

```
@ManagedBean("myBean")
public class Bean{
   property HtmlForm myform;
}
```

on event, create a new instance of the input component

```
HtmlInputText input=new HtmlInputText();
```

and attach to the your form

```
myform.getChildren().add(input);
```

Comment: Please never create new component instances yourself. The prefered way is this: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `h:dataTable` to add elements dynamically... Have a list of any type you want to provide values for dataTable...

In `h:dataTable`... you can include the element tag to create inside `<h:column>`

It will be used to generate elements you want to create dynamically.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow! This answer doesn't seem to add anything substantial on top of the already given answers so far. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum where everyone repeats each other on agreement, but it is a question&answer site where everyone gives an upvote on agreement or a downvote on disagreement. If you earn 15 reputation, then you can cast upvotes.