# Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> on a List<String> doesn't update model values

Tags: string, list, jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

Here is the scenario (simplified):

There is a bean (call it `mrBean`) with a member and the appropriate getters/setters:

```
private List<String> rootContext;

public void addContextItem() {
    rootContext.add("");
}
```

The JSF code:

```
<h:form id="a_form">
            <ui:repeat value="#{mrBean.stringList}" var="stringItem">
                    <h:inputText value="#{stringItem}" />
            </ui:repeat>
            <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{mrBean.addContextItem}">
                <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The problem is, when clicking the "Add" button, the values that were entered in the `<h:inputText/>` that represent the Strings in the `stringList` aren't executed.

Actually, the `mrBean.stringList` setter (`setStringList(List<String> stringList)`) is never called.

Any idea why?

Some info -
I'm using MyFaces JSF 2.0 on Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `String` class is immutable and doesn't have a setter for the value. The getter is basically the `Object#toString()` method.

You need to get/set the value directly on the `List` instead. You can do that by the list index which is available by `<ui:repeat varStatus>`.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{mrBean.stringList}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:inputText value="#{mrBean.stringList[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

You don't need a setter for the `stringList` either. EL will get the item by `List#get(index)` and set the item by `List#add(index,item)`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured the problem was with the values being immutable but I didn't know if JSF could somehow overcome this. This really explains it so thanks.

Comment: So, loop.index here returns the index of the current element of the list?