# JSF h:selectBooleanCheckbox inside ui:repeat - varStatus.index works, var doesn't

Tags: jsf, mojarra, uirepeat

Can someone please explain this phenomenon?

I am using Mojarra 2.1.6 - Glassfish 3.1.2.

I have a checkbox inside a `ui:repeat`.  The `ui:repeat` is looping over a list of booleans from my managed bean.  Each individual checkbox is bound to an element of that list.  For example:

```
<ui:repeat var="checkbox" value="#{checkboxTestBean.list}" varStatus="status">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{checkbox}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

The problem is the values aren't getting applied to the managed bean.  When I submit and re-render the form, the values don't stick.

*However*, if I index into the managed bean element explicitly, by changing `value=#{checkbox}` above to `value="#{checkboxTestBean.list[status.index]}"`, everything works.

Any ideas why that might be the case?

XHTML:

```
<h:form>
<div>
Using value="#\{var\}"
<ui:repeat var="checkbox" value="#{checkboxTestBean.list}" varStatus="status">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{checkbox}"/>
</ui:repeat>
</div>

<div>
Using value="#\{varStatus.index\}"
<ui:repeat var="checkbox" value="#{checkboxTestBean.list}" varStatus="status">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{checkboxTestBean.list[status.index]}"/>
</ui:repeat>
</div>
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{checkboxTestBean.actionListener}">
PROCESS FORM
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Java:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CheckboxTestBean {

public List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

public CheckboxTestBean() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        list.add(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}

public void actionListener(ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("*** dumping whole form");
    System.out.println("*** list = " + list);
}

public List<Boolean> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<Boolean> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `Boolean` as being an immutable class doesn't have a setter method for the value. When referencing it as a list item by index instead, EL will be able to set the new value on the `List` by index like so `list.add(status.index, newValue)`. An alternative is to make it a property of a mutable model class and have a collection of it instead like so `List<Item>` which you reference by `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.checkbox}"/>`.

This is not specifically related to `Boolean`, you would have exactly the same problem when using for example `List<String>` in an `<ui:repeat><h:inputText>`.

#### See also:

- [Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> on a List<String> doesn't update model values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780858/jsf-2-executing-values-in-uirepeat-doesnt-commit-the-values/10784078#10784078)

Comment: Thanks!  Considering all the problems with inputs inside ui:repeat, I assumed it could have been another Mojarra bug.  Working-as-designed because the EL expression directly references an immutable object is the last thing I would have expected.