# jsf dynamic inputtext fields

Tags: jsf, datatable

I'm making a datatable where you can add exrta rows. In this extra rows, there's a inputtext. After putting something in the inputtext, this value should be saved to a list. But it's not. I tried in the method below using Sting as a parameter, but then to a list was saved : "`javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@23sdf`" and thing like that. When I changed method to javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText method below returns null.

here's code of table:

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{correct.newPowody}" var="z" binding="#{table}" >
    <h:inputText binding="#{custom}" value="#{z}">
        <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{correct.newPowodyAdder(table.rowIndex, custom)}"
                                    execute="@this" render="@form"/>
    </h:inputText>
    </h:dataTable>
```

here is my correct bean code:

```
    public void newPowodyAdder(int rowIndex, javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText powod) {
        String value = powod.getValue().toString();
        this.newPowody.set(rowIndex, value);
    }
}
```

this method just should add data from inputtext into a list. Thank you for help

Comment: Make sure your bean is `@SessionScoped`. If you're using JSF 2.2, then you can use `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Changing to @SessionScoped did not solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

This code really isn't making any sense. It's an overcomplicated attempt to fix the simple problem of `String` class being immutable. Don't use `<h:inputText value="#{string}"`. Just use brace notation `[]` in EL to reference a list item by index like so `value="#{bean.strings[index]}"`:

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{table}" value="#{correct.newPowody}">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{correct.newPowody[table.rowIndex]}" />
    </h:column> 
</h:dataTable>
```

That's all. No ajax listener method mess necessary.

#### See also:

- [Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> on a List<String> doesn't update model values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780858/using-uirepeathinputtext-on-a-liststring-doesnt-update-model-values/)

Comment: i do used like this but in my array data will not stored i used RequestScope  any problem with this scope