# Using <h:dataTable><h:inputText> on a List<String> doesn't update model values

Tags: string, jsf, input, datatable

I've the below data table:

```
<h:dataTable var="row" value="#{myBean.listOfStrings}">
    <h:column> 
         <h:inputText value="#{row}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Which is tied to a `List<String>`:

```
private List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getListOfStrings() {
    return listOfStrings;
}

public void setListOfStrings(List<String> listOfStrings) {
    this.listOfStrings = listOfStrings;
}
```

When I enter a value in the field and save the form it is not passing the value to the field in the list, it is setting `null`, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: We need full bean class declaration. My wild guess: check the scope of the bean.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo the bean is in the session.

Comment: It has to be inside a form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `String` class is immutable. It doesn't have a setter for the instance value. The getter is in this construct basically the `Object#toString()` method as implicitly called by EL, which coincidentally returns the string value itself.

You need to set the changed value as a new list item instead. You can do this via the brace notation on the list whereby you pass the list index: `#{myBean.listOfStrings[index]}`.

So, this should do, making use of [`UIData#getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex%28%29) as list index:

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{table}" value="#{myBean.listOfStrings}" var="row">
    <h:column> 
         <h:inputText value="#{myBean.listOfStrings[table.rowIndex]}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

*(note: the value expression of `binding` is as-is! don't bind it to a bean property)*

#### See also:

- [Using <ui:repeat><h:inputText> on a List<String> doesn't update model values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780858/using-uirepeathinputtext-on-a-liststring-doesnt-update-model-values/10784078#10784078)
- [What is component binding in JSF? When it is preferred to be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used)

Comment: What if I have more than one table on my page? The binding won't work right?

Comment: Of course not. Just give it a different name. `binding="#{table1}"`, `binding="#{table2}"`, etc or whatever is most self-documenting, e.g. `binding="#{listOfValuesTable}"` (expect that "listOfValues" is absolutely not self-documenting, think of `binding="#{productsTable}" value="#{bean.products}"`).