# Using <ui:repeat>, <h:inputText>and <f:validateWholeBean> on a List<String>

Tags: jsf

I want to gather a dynamic number of values in a list via `<ui:repeat>` and `<h:inputText>` and I'm using:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{mrBean.stringList}" varStatus="loop">
  <h:inputText value="#{mrBean.stringList[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784078/5428477), this works perfectly well. If I add `<f:validateWholeBean>` like this:

```
<h:form>
  ...
  <h:inputText value="#{mrBean.someIntValue}">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="3" maximum="128"/>
    <f:validateBean validationGroups="com.example.minimalfaces.ListValidationGroup"/>
  </h:input>
  ...
  <ui:repeat value="#{mrBean.stringList}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:inputText value="#{mrBean.stringList[loop.index]}">
      <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="10"/>
      <f:validateBean validationGroups="com.example.minimalfaces.ListValidationGroup"/>
    </h:inputText>
  </ui:repeat>
  ...
  <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{mrBean.action()}" />
  
  <f:validateWholeBean validationGroups="com.example.minimalfaces.ListValidationGroup" value="#{mrBean}"/>
</h:form>
```

the values for the list are not visible in the `isValid(...)` method (just the initial values) of the `ConstraintValidator<...,...>` implementation (all scalar values are present).

The [documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/f/validatewholebean) says: *...Populate the copied bean with the candidate values...*, is there a way to peer into this population process, to find out, what went wrong?

Thanks in advance.