# JSF 2.0 Dynamically Remove Components

Tags: datatable, components, jsf-2, dynamic

As a follow on to an answered question on Adding Components Dynamically in JSF 2.0 (see link below), I like the approach of using a dataTable, but what about Removing one of the added components?

[How to dynamically add JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code snippet in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically) you linked, you need to do the following changes:

1. Add a column with a delete button to the table.

   ```
   <h:column><h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{bean.delete}" /></h:column>
   ```
2. Add a [`DataModel<Item>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) property to the bean and wrap the list of items in it so that you will be able to obtain the table row where the button was clicked.

   ```
   private DataModel<Item> model = new ListDataModel<Item>(items);
   ```

   *(don't forget the getter, note that you can also instantiate this in bean constructor or postconstruct)*
3. Use this in the datatable instead.

   ```
   <h:dataTable value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
   ```
4. Add a delete method to the bean.

   ```
   public void delete() {
       items.remove(model.getRowData());
   }
   ```

#### See also:

- [Benefits and pitfalls of `@ViewScoped`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) - contains JSF 2.0 CRUD table example