# JSF2: Building JSF2 views (whole component trees) at runtime

Tags: dynamic, components, jsf-2

Currently I'm trying JSF 2.0 and still learning the more advanced features.
JSF2 is comfortable when having to deal with *pre-defined* views (fixed component trees) whose widgets are completely known at compile time -- of course with the exception of repeating data list/table entries and light dynamic modification of forms via the DataTable "trick" (as I read here, especially under [JSF2, can I add JSF components dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically) and [How to create dynamic JSF 1.2 form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-1-2-form-fields)).

Now I'm wondering about the realization of completely dynamic JSF2 component trees, where a web user, for each given content type (e.g. 'Person', 'PersonList' but also 'PersonalManagementPanel'), can choose one from a list of content-type compatible widgets (=JSF custom components).
As result, this user will always see the "Personal Manager Page" rendered with his/her prefered "PersonalManagerPanel", which in turn also renders its nested components ('Person', 'PersonList') with the user's preferred variants.

Obviously, the goal is to get a selectively configurable/customizable JSF Page -- at runtime.

1. Is this scenario realizable in JSF2? -- How could this be done?
2. Are there more appropriate Java technologies for this requierement? 
   -- One possible alternative I'm thinking of is XML plus XSLT.

Thank you very much for your help and suggestions.

Best regards
  Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<ui:include src="#{bean.template}" />
```

Or if you want more complicated components, you should take a look at the [PreRenderViewEvent](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/event/PreRenderViewEvent.html).

Note that there are issues with both solutions.

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-770
- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1708
- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2041