# primefaces partially submit datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I needed to create a datatable with the functionality described here [How to dynamically add JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically)

It works, but in my form, besides this datatable I have other elements. I needed that when the add button is clicked, only the data entered in the datatable is submitted besides creating the new field. But the values to contact.email are always null. I'm trying to use primefaces commandbutton.

```
<h:form>
//other elements
 <h:panelGrid id="region" columns="1">
  <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.addContact}" update="region"  value="add" immediate="true" process="region @this" ajax="true"/>
    <h:dataTable id="addContacts" value="#{myBean.contacts}" var="contact">
    <h:column>
        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{contact.email}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

How can I make this partial submit work?

Thanks

Comment: Sure that your bean is `@ViewScoped`, exactly as shown in the linked answer? If it's `@RequestScoped`, it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

In PrimeFaces try using prependId="false" attribute in the form

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

Comment: **never** use `prependId="false"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render

Answer (score -1):

use commas to separate the components you want to partially submit

```
process="@this,addContacts"
```