# How to make form input fields for a many objects?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am making an administrating interface for an mobile application that I made. I have a question entity and a answer entity. Multiple answer objects (between 3-5) belongs to a single question object.

I am making a interface where I can register a new question with answers, how do I do that? In the backing bean I have a Question object and then I bind the properties to the input fields, but I don't know what to do with the Answers? And is it possible to make let say 4 input fields and have a button saying "Add answer" which makes a new input html tag?

(I am using Java EE 6 with all reference implementations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are specific to a question, right? Make the answers a property of the question.

```java
public class Question {

    private List<Answer> answers;

    // ...
}
```

In your admin interface you could use an iterating component such as a `<h:dataTable>` to present multiple answers and add/remove them. See also [How to dynamically add JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically)