# Dynamically added component are growing vertically

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am following the option suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3409511/1175065) to dynamically adding inputtext box in my PrimeFaces v3.5 application. The only problem I am facing is that the newly added inputtext are growing vertically. Screenshot is attached.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h:dataTable>` generates a HTML `<table>` element wherein each iteration generates a `<tr>` element which represents naturally a new row.

If you don't want to generate a table at all, then you should not be using a `<h:dataTable>`, but e.g. `<ui:repeat>`.

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
    </ui:repeat>
    <h:commandButton value="add" action="#{bean.add}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

This doesn't generate any markup and the HTML `<input>` elements will [by default](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) end up in a single line.

Comment: Just one more query. I am using `<p:commandButton actionListener="#{repeateRun.addVal}" update="runList" />` I don't wanna update entire form so i am trying to update only  `<ui:repeat  id="runList">` part. but thats not happening. Any hack for this?

Comment: As answered, the `<ui:repeat>` doesn't generate any markup. Logically, wrap it in a component which generates something to HTML so that it's accessible/updateable by JavaScript/Ajax. A panel group with an `id`, for example?