# Add a new p:SelectOneMenu to a JSF page dynamically from the Backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans, selectonemenu

i want to add dynamically an new p:SelectOneMenu to my panelGrid here

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel_grid" columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px"cellpadding="5" >

   <p:outputLabel for="firstQuestionDropDown" value={InsererAffaireController.firstQuestion.libeleQuestion}"
   <p:selectOneMenu id="firstQuestionDropDown" value="#{InsererAffaireController.firstQuestion.libeleQuestion}" style="width:150px">
      <p:ajax listener="#{InsererAffaireController.displayNextQuestion()}" update="panel_grid" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{InsererAffaireController.firstQuestion.listLibeleReponses}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

            <!-- Here i want to add my new SelectOneMenu -->    
</h:panelGrid>
```

I managed to do that from the managed bean but the problem is that i can't populate the new SelectOneMenu and i don't know how to add a f:selectItems to it
here is the method that add the new p:SelectOneMenu to the panel grid but it still empty

```
    public void displayNextQuestion() {
       nextQuestion = getNextQuestion();
       OutputLabel nextQuestionLabelUI = new OutputLabel();
       nextQuestionLabelUI.setValue(nextQuestion.getLibeleQuestion());

       SelectOneMenu nextQuestionDropDown = new SelectOneMenu() ;

       List<SelectItem> selectItems = new ArrayList<>();

       for (String s : nextQuestion.getListLibeleReponses()) {

        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(s, s));
        System.out.println(selectItems.get(0).getLabel());
       }
       // How can i add the selectitems to the SelectOneMenu
       UIComponent panelGrid = findComponent("panel_grid");
       panelGrid.getChildren().add(nextQuestionLabelUI);
       panelGrid.getChildren().add(nextQuestionDropDown) ;
       RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("panel_grid");

}
```

Comment: This all is the wrong approach. The correct approach is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3409053

Comment: i tried your approach and it's work for me but could you tell me why adding new UI components from the managed bean it's wrong ?

Comment: Very verbose and cumbersome to maintain. XML+XHTML is a language much more suitable for declaring tree structures than Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UISelectItems` class like this:

```
...
UISelectItems selectItemsComponent = new UISelectItems();
selectItemsComponent.setValue(selectItems);
nextQuestionDropDown.getChildren().add(selectItemsComponent);
...
```