# How to insert body in composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I am watching this [wiki info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) concerning the composite components; Here is  the snippet :

```
package com.example;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;

@FacesComponent("ratingComponent")
public class RatingComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    public Object[] getItems() {
        Object totalStars = getAttributes().get("totalStars");
        int size = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(totalStars));
        return new Object[size];
    }

}
```

And then it's usage :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.products}" var="product">
    <h:column>#{product.name}</h:column>
    <h:column><my:rating score="#{product.rating}" /></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

the taglib.xml *(I am testing with)*
...

```
<tag>
   <tag-name>rating</tag-name> 
   <component>
     <component-type>ratingComponent</component-type>
   </component>
</tag>
```

...

I am just wondering how to make **my:rating** tag be able to contain **`<ui:insert/>`** which should make possible to use **my:rating** in this way :

```
<my:rating score="#{product.rating}" >
  <h:panelGrid border="1" columns="1" layout="block">
     <h:panelGroup><label value="Lovely stars"/></h:panelGroup>
      etc...
  </h:panelGrid>
</my:rating>
```

So my question is... if component is the composite one how to make it insert-able?

Thanks

Comment: Advice: get terminology and separate concepts right based on http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822000. Do note that a composite doesn't require a taglib file at all.

Comment: @BalusC No, I am interested in converting the composite into tag for possible lib packing :S Is there a way to make UIComponent insert-able or if it is <source> it can be insert-able or if it is <component-type> it should use add() way only? I mean how to combine static and dynamic components?

Comment: If model is static during the view scope: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3510614 If model is dynamic during the view scope: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3409053