# What's the recommended JSF 2.0 scope for a CRUD application?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, crud

I was wondering which scope to use for a CRUD Application. Using @ReqeustScoped causes an access to the database for every request. With @SessionScoped, data can be cached in the managed bean, but can cause the so called session-bloat. Moreover, it is more difficult to keep the data up to date. What would you recommend? Is there a best-practice solution.
Thanks,
Theo

Comment: I built a basic architecture for CRUD components only with @RequestScoped, and caching data. http://bluefoot.info/?p=408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, you want the scope there in between: [`@ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html). This scope lives as long as you're submitting and navigating to the same view.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 new features, View Scope](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_new_feature6)
- [CRUD in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks) (with code example)

Comment: I believe this answer is tightly coupled to a specific solution which is making all the operations inside a single view/xhtml file. If one were to have three views: 1 for the record list, 1 for the detail view and 1 for the form (create and update) the answer would be either one SessionScoped bean (solution in most tutorials and code generators like NetBeans and MyEclipse) or "it depends", maybe 1 RequestScoped bean for the list and view and 1 ViewScoped bean for the form (considering AJAX components) and using input hidden to preserve the id.