# h:commandButton can NOT submit parameters to backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf

I would like to submit a key value to my backing bean so that I know which person within a collection user trying to update. I think I need to used f:param to do so, but somehow it does not work. It will submit the value just fine if I use af:commandButton instead of h:commandButton.

Here is my button:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="cntctmBtn" value="Update" action="#{pullForm.updateDependent}">
   <f:param name="selectedIndex" value="#{loop.index}" />
   <f:param name="selectedEDI" value="#{eachOne.identifier.dodEdiPnId}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

and here is how I am trying to get my submitted values out.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String edi_tmp = (String)map.get("selectedEDI");
```

But I got the ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the button is inside a `<h:dataTable>` or any other [`UIData`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) component, then you should be retrieving the "current" row object by [`UIData#getRowData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowData%28%29) or [`DataModel#getRowData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#getRowData%28%29). No need to pass the row identifier around as parameter or so.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    private List<Person> persons;
    private DataModel<Person> personModel;

    public Bean() {
        persons = loadItSomehow();
        personModel = new ListDataModel<Person>(persons);
    }

    public void update() {
        Person selectedPerson = personModel.getRowData(); // There it is.
        // ...
    }

    // Add/generate getters/setters/etc.
}
```

with

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.personModel}" var="person">
        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="update" action="#{bean.update}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Keep it simple.

#### See also:

- [CRUD example with @ViewScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks)