# JSF 2 how to get selected row from h:dataTable in backing bean

Tags: jsf-2

How can i get the selected rows bean.id from h:dataTable in a backing bean?
f:ajax with f:param inside h:column didn't work for me.
Any suggestions (not using h:commandLink since i want the row to be chosen anywhere)?

Comment: Duplicate of [h:commandButton can NOT submit parameters to backing bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711351/hcommandbutton-can-not-submit-parameters-to-backing-bean)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate since i don't want to use a commandLink/commandButton but click the row anywhere.

Comment: @BalusC asking you here to avoid a duplicate but can ask as a new question if you want.Is there no way to make whole table row clickable\selectable like  richfaces allows not just the text. I mean just allow click any where on the row using just JSF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually BalusC's comment is good enough, although i added a small improvement, so that h:commandLink will look like a h:outputText and that it will occupy the whole table cell so that you get the effect of clicking the cell anywhere (not only the text).
So what i did is adding a small CSS:

```
table tr td a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0px 2px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    width: 160px;
}
```