# Primefaces Inline DataTable Delete functionality

Tags: datatable, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces inline editing datatable.which consists of primefaces RowEditor and a CommandButton to delete the record.My Problem is when i deleted any record from the the database,the row is successfully deleted and the deleted record is showing when i click on the edit button for editing the next record.This edit problem continues with all the records .It is showing the present value in h:outputText and the old value in h:inputText which comes when we click on edit button.
Could anyone help me on this ?
Thankyou all.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of Primefaces bugs logged on the `<p:dataTable>` component, so I am not going to search through all of them.

I do know however that there is an open bug as of Primefaces 2.2.1 stating that components within a row of a `<p:dataTable>` will not correctly update (refresh) the appropriate values within the dataTable.  This problem MAY be fixed in Primefaces 3.0.  If you are interested you can search the known bugs [here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list).

Fortunately I have figured out a workaround for this.  You need to perform an asynchronous operation from a component OUTSIDE of the `<p:dataTable>` and make sure that component sets the id of the dataTable in its `update` attribute.

```
<h:form id="form1">
  <p:commandButton widgetVar="updateButton" update="form1:table1" ... />
  <p:dataTable id="table1" ...>
    <p:column ...>
      <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" action="#{managedBean.doDelete}" oncomplete="javascriptFunction();" ... />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And in a javascript:

```
function javascriptFunction() {
  updateButton.jq.click();
}
```

Comment: Very useful answer, if somebody wants to hide that button and have the functionality just add in button `style="visibility:hidden"` HTH

Comment: @HTH Yes, however `visibility:hidden` does not work correctly on all browsers.  A better option for hiding the button is `display: none;`