# PrimeFaces update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a databable with the following definition :

```
   <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:dataTable id="instancesTable" lazy="false" paginator="false" var="instance"
                     value="#{panaceaController.instances}">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Directory"/>
                </f:facet>

                <p:commandLink value="#{instance.directory}" target = "instance.jsf">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
             <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Running"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{instance.running}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Options
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandLink id="properties_link" async="true" update="propertiesTable" oncomplete="propertiesDialog.show();">
                    <h:graphicImage value="img/properties.png" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:tooltip for="properties_link" value="Edit Properties" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />

                <p:commandLink id="delete" async="true"  onclick="confirmDelete.show();" >
                    <h:graphicImage value="img/edit-delete.png"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:tooltip for="delete" value="Delete This Instance" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />


                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!instance.running}">
                <p:commandLink id="start" async="true" action="#{panaceaController.start}" update="messages instancesTable">
                    <h:graphicImage value="img/start.png"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:tooltip for="start" value="Start Instance" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{instance.running}">
                <p:commandLink id="stop" async="true" action="#{panaceaController.stop}" update="messages instancesTable">
                    <h:graphicImage value="img/stop.png"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:tooltip for="stop" value="Stop Instance" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                  <p:commandLink id="probe" async="true" action="#{panaceaController.probe}" update="messages instancesTable">
                    <h:graphicImage value="img/probe.png"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{instance}" target="#{panaceaController.instance}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:tooltip for="probe" value="Probe if instance is running" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />

            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
      </h:form>
```

The delete commandLink updates the table OK, but other commands simply don't update the "instancesTable" even though they update the "messages" correctly. I am using primefaces 3.0M3

Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of bugs associated with AJAX updates of a dataTable component for actions triggered within components of a dataTable.  Most of these should have been fixed in the latest Primefaces version 3 release however you didn't really state which version of Primefaces you are using.

I posted a workaround to this in a [previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422151/primefaces-inline-datatable-delete-functionality/6424863#6424863).  Essentially you would from the client side invoke a javascript to manually invoke a click event on a hidden button outside of the dataTable.

Comment: I am using 3.0M3. I will have a look at your workaround and try upgrading to M4.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to surround dataTable with a outputpanel, and gives the outputpanel a styleClass(This styleClass is for update only.), and then updates the outputpanel by styleClass just like this:`update="@(.yourPanelStyleClass)"`. It works well in my case, but I`m not sure if it works well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the ID of the component which you want to update in the commandbutton
 update="instancesTable"