# <f:setPropertyActionListener /> : no update

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf, primefaces

i have a problem with the `<f:setPropertyActionListener />` property. Fields are not updated with the values saved in the target. when i debug i found that the target is initialised with the value but it doesnt work when i try to extract data in xhtm page.

Here is the Code:

> ```
> <f:view>
> <h:head>
> ```

```
</h:head>
<h:body>

<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <p:commandLink value="Ajouter" oncomplete="newcatDialog.show()" />  

<p:dataTable  value="#{categorieBean.categories}" var="categ"  id="table" >
<f:facet name="header"> 
  <h:outputText value="Catégories" /> 
</f:facet>
 <p:column>
 <h:outputText id="id" value="#{categ.id}"/>
 </p:column>
 <p:column>
 <h:outputText id="nom" value="#{categ.nom}"/>
 </p:column>

 <p:column>
    <p:commandLink   update="display"  value="Modifier" onclick="catDialog.show()" >  
       <f:setPropertyActionListener  value="#{categ}"  
            target="#{categorieBean.selectedCategorie}" />
    </p:commandLink>                       
 </p:column>


</p:dataTable>



  <p:dialog id="creation" header="Catégorie" widgetVar="newcatDialog" resizable="false" 
      autoSized="true" modal="true">

    <h:panelGrid id="ceationDisplay" columns="2" cellpadding="4"> 
     <h:column><h:outputText value="Nom: " /></h:column>
           <h:column>
             <h:inputText value="#{categorieBean.nom}" />
           </h:column>
           <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="Description: " />
           </h:column>
           <h:column>
             <h:inputText value="#{categorieBean.desc}" />
           </h:column> 
           <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="Photo: " />
           </h:column>
           <h:column>
             <p:fileUpload value="#{categorieBean.fichier}"  mode="simple" auto="true"
             allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />  

           </h:column>
           <h:column>
            <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer"
                             actionListener="#{categorieBean.ajouter}" 
                             oncomplete="newcatDialog.hide()"
                             update="table"
                             ajax="false"
                             >

            </p:commandButton>
           </h:column>
           <h:column>   
            <p:commandButton value="Annuler" oncomplete="newcatDialog.hide()" ></p:commandButton>
           </h:column> 
           </h:panelGrid>


  </p:dialog>   
</h:form>

<!-- ************************ -->

  <p:dialog id="modification" header="Catégorie" widgetVar="catDialog"  resizable="false" 
      autoSized="true" modal="true" appendToBody="true">
    <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4"> 
     <h:column><h:outputText value="Nom: " /></h:column>
           <h:column>
             <h:inputText value="#{categorieBean.selectedCategorie.nom}" />
           </h:column>
           <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="Description: " />
           </h:column>
           <h:column>
             <h:inputText value="#{categorieBean.selectedCategorie.desc}" />
           </h:column> 
           <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="Photo: " />
           </h:column>
           <h:column>
             <p:fileUpload value="#{categorieBean.fichiermodif}"  mode="simple" auto="true"
             allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />  

           </h:column>
           <h:column>
            <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer"
                             actionListener="#{categorieBean.modifier}" 
                             oncomplete="catDialog.hide()"
                             update="table"
                             ajax="false"
                             >

            </p:commandButton>
           </h:column>
           <h:column>   
            <p:commandButton value="Annuler"     oncomplete="catDialog.hide()" ></p:commandButton>
           </h:column> 
           </h:panelGrid>
      </h:form>

  </p:dialog>

</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

and Here is the Backing Bean:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
import tn.projet.model.Categorie;
import tn.projet.service.CategorieService;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;




public class CategorieBean implements Serializable{



//DI via Spring

private CategorieService categorieService;
private List<Categorie> categories;
private String nom;
private String desc;
private Categorie selectedCategorie;
private String image;
private UploadedFile fichier;
private UploadedFile fichiermodif;


@PostConstruct
public void init()
    {


        this.categories = new ArrayList<Categorie>();

        categories=categorieService.listerCategorie();

    }

/***********GETTERS/SETTERS**********/

public UploadedFile getFichiermodif() {
    return fichiermodif;
}

public void setFichiermodif(UploadedFile fichiermodif) {
    this.fichiermodif = fichiermodif;
}

public UploadedFile getFichier() {
    return fichier;
}

public void setFichier(UploadedFile fichier) {
    this.fichier = fichier;
}



public CategorieBean() {

}


public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}


    public CategorieService getCategorieService() {
    return categorieService;
}


public void setCategorieService(CategorieService categorieService) {
    this.categorieService = categorieService;
}






//recupérer la liste des catégories
public List<Categorie> getCategories()
{

return categories;
}


public Categorie getSelectedCategorie() {


    return this.selectedCategorie;
    }



public void setSelectedCategorie(Categorie select) {
    this.selectedCategorie =  select;
    }


public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}




/**************CRUD***********************/
 //recupération du fichier image uploadé
public String creerFichier(UploadedFile fich) throws Exception{

    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();

    String retour =fich.getFileName();

    String aux_f = servletContext.getRealPath("/")+retour;   

    File result = new File( aux_f); 

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(result);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[6124];

        int bulk;
        InputStream inputStream = fich.getInputstream();
        while (true) {
            bulk = inputStream.read(buffer);
            if (bulk < 0) {
                break;
            }
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bulk);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
        }

        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();




    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return retour;
}



    public void modifier()
    {
        if(fichiermodif!=null)
        {
            try {
                String imagemodif= creerFichier(fichiermodif);
                selectedCategorie.setImage(imagemodif);
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        }

        categorieService.modifierCategorie(selectedCategorie);
    }
    //add a new Categorie data into database
    public void ajouter(){

        if(fichiermodif!=null)
        {
            try {
                image= creerFichier(fichier);
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        }


        Categorie cat = new Categorie();
        cat.setNom(getNom());
        cat.setDesc(getDesc());
        cat.setImage(image);
        categorieService.ajouterCategorie(cat);

        }


  /******************actionListener****************/
    public void edit(){

        System.out.println("selectedCategorie.getNom()");

    }



}
```

Comment: What version of Primefaces do you use?

Comment: i am using the latest version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a bug with the Primefaces dataTable component in 2.2.1 where a postback triggered from within the dataTable does not cause components to update.

I posted a workaround in a [previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422151/primefaces-inline-datatable-delete-functionality/6424863#6424863).