# dynamic inputtextfields

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to create dynamic input textfields with labels using primefaces.
Like if I click the add button it should keep adding a label and a input textfields.
What component I can use ? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `<h:dataTable>` in combination with a `@ViewScoped` bean for this.

E.g.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="inputs" value="#{bean.inputs}" var="input">
        <h:column>
            <p:outputLabel for="input" value="#{input.label}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <p:inputText id="input" value="#{input.value}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.add}" update="inputs" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<Input> inputs;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        inputs = new ArrayList<Input>();
    }

    public void add() {
        Input input = new Input();
        input.setLabel("Input " + (inputs.size() + 1));
        inputs.add(input);
    }

    public List<Input> getInputs() {
        return inputs;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Input {

    private String label;
    private String value;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

You can of course also use a `<p:dataTable>`, but that would only add some fancy look'n'feel which is likely unnecessary for this particular use case.

#### See also:

- [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks/3180885#3180885)

Comment: I didnt know that we can use inputtextfields inside datatable. thank you very much.

Comment: I will try to use collector as well, and will see which one suit better

Comment: @BalusC How we can add remove functionality for added items?

Comment: @mabuzer: this is shown in the example behind the "see also" link.