# Use ArrayList , it store current data , but previous data is remove from arrayList

Tags: jsf-2

I use a arrayList. I want data store in it from Entity class.But it store current data and previous data remove from it.
My JSF page Code:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="ID"/><br/>
        <h:inputText value="#{dataTestBeans.data.id}"/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="Name"/><br/>
        <h:inputText value="#{dataTestBeans.data.name}"/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="Address"/><br/>
        <h:inputText value="#{dataTestBeans.data.address}"/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="Birth Day"/><br/>
        <h:inputText value="#{dataTestBeans.data.birthDay}"/><br/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{dataTestBeans.abc}" value="Submit" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form>
        <c:forEach items="#{dataTestBeans.testArray}" var="dataTest">
            <h:outputText value="#{dataTest.id}"/><br/>
            <h:outputText value="#{dataTest.name}"/><br/>
            <h:outputText value="#{dataTest.address}"/><br/>
            <h:outputText value="#{dataTest.birthDay}"/><br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
 </html>
```

My Entity Class code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "person")
@SessionScoped
public class Person{

private String id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String birthDay;

public Person() {
}
    //getter and setter all veriable

}
```

My controller Beans code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="dataTestBeans")
@SessionScoped
public class DataTestBeans {

private Person dataArray;
private List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();   

public DataTestBeans() {
 }

public Person getData() {
  if (dataArray == null) {
      dataArray = new Person();
  }
 return dataArray;
 }

public void abc() {
   person.add(dataArray);
 }

public List<Person> getTestArray() {
  return person;
 }

public void setTestArray(List<Person> person) {
    this.person = person;
  }
}
```

When I run it show the current data

Comment: Whats is this `data` in `#{dataTestBeans.data.id}` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the **same** reference for every data entry. Hence you're basically overwriting it everytime. You should be creating a **new** one after you've added the filled entry in your `abc()` method.

Replace the following part in your current code:

```
private TestArray dataArray;
private List<TestArray> testArray = new ArrayList<TestArray>();

public DataTestBeans() {
}

public TestArray getData() {
    if (dataArray == null) {
        dataArray = new TestArray();
    }
    return dataArray;
 }

public void abc() {
    testArray.add(dataArray);
}
```

by

```
private TestArray dataArray;
private List<TestArray> testArray;

public DataTestBeans() {
    dataArray = new TestArray();
    testArray = new ArrayList<TestArray>()
}

public TestArray getData() {
    return dataArray;
 }

public void abc() {
    testArray.add(dataArray);
    dataArray = new TestArray();
}
```

#### See also:

- [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks/3180885#3180885) (a better CRUD example)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your class and variable namings are non-sensible and very confusing and therefore it's hard for others to quickly interpret the code and spot the problem. Rename `TestArray` to `Person`, rename `dataArray` to `person`, rename `testArray` to `persons` and rename `DataTestBeans` to `PersonManager` or something and your code becomes instantly much more self-documenting and easier to interpret.

```
private Person person;
private List<Person> persons;

public PersonManager() {
    person = new Person();
    persons = new ArrayList<Person>()
}

public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
 }

public void add() {
    persons.add(person);
    person = new Person();
}
```