# Submit data in one form from another form JSF

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

When edit is selected, the backing bean is called but the form fields are not pre filled with the data.

```
<h:form id="EmpDetails">
   <h:inputText value="#{empBean.fName}">
      <f:validateBean disabled="#{param[skipBeanValidation]}"/>
    </h:inputText>

<h:dataTable> 
 <h:column>
    [<h:commandLink value="Edit" immediate="true">
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{empBean.edit}"/>
     </h:commandLink>  ]
     Changed to 
     <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{empBean.edit}">
       <f:param name="skipValidation" value="true"/>
     </h:comamndLink>
  </h:column>     
 </h:dataTable>

<h:commandLink value="#{empBean.addEmployee}"/>
<h:commandLink value="#{empBean.continue}"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't how HTML forms are supposed to work. A single HTML form should surround *all* input elements and buttons which all participate in the *same* form.

Put the related form elements together in the same form. If you encounter a problem with it, then it has to be solved differently. For example, by using partial submits in ajax.

Comment: I have updated the code to use only one form. The edit functionality is not working as required.

Comment: Remove the `immediate="true"` and `execute="@form"`. If that didn't solve your concrete problem, then you'd have to tell a bit more than "not working". In any way, you may find this CRUD example helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180885

Comment: That's exactly why you should *also* remove the `execute="@form"`. It defaults then to `@this`.

Comment: Removing immediate="true" & execute="@form" the listener is not called.

Comment: And with them, it *is* called?

Comment: Yes, adding those attributes, there is a call to the listener.

Comment: I find it hard to believe. Do you have the complete code as shown in your question also running in your test page? Or does your question represent a simplified (and untested) version of it? In any way, have you given the kickoff CRUD example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180885 a try? It's copy'n'paste'n'runnable.

Comment: I tried something similar to the CRUD example, but because of different requirements (placement of buttons) I had to use a single form instead of two forms for edit and save button.

Comment: Okay, let's assume that your example is incomplete and that you really need the immediate attribute for some unclear reason, can you please describe how exactly it "is not working"?

Comment: I have updated the code, now I use f:param to pass in a attribute whether or not to validate the fields.